# in_axes keyword in JAX's vmap

Tags: jax, auto-vectorization

I'm trying to understand JAX's auto-vectorization capabilities using `vmap` and implemented a minimal working example based on JAX's documentation.

I don't understand how `in_axes` is used correctly. In the example below I can set `in_axes=(None, 0)` or `in_axes=(None, 1)` leading to the same results. Why is that the case?

And why do I have to use `in_axes=(None, 0)` and not something like `in_axes=(0, )`?

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import vmap


def predict(params, input_vec):
    assert input_vec.ndim == 1
    activations = input_vec
    for W, b in params:
        outputs = jnp.dot(W, activations) + b
        activations = jnp.tanh(outputs)
    return outputs


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Parameters
    dims = [2, 3, 5]
    input_dims = dims[0]
    batch_size = 2

    # Weights
    params = list()
    for dims_in, dims_out in zip(dims, dims[1:]):
        params.append((jnp.ones((dims_out, dims_in)), jnp.ones((dims_out,))))

    # Input data
    input_batch = jnp.ones((batch_size, input_dims))

    # With vmap
    predictions = vmap(predict, in_axes=(None, 0))(params, input_batch)
    print(predictions)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`in_axes=(None, 0)` means that the first argument (here `params`) will not be mapped, while the second argument (here `input_vec`) will be mapped along axis 0.

> In the example below I can set `in_axes=(None, 0)` or `in_axes=(None, 1)` leading to the same results. Why is that the case?

This is because `input_vec` is a 2x2 matrix of ones, so whether you map along axis 0 or axis 1, the input vectors are length-2 vectors of ones. In more general cases, the two specifications are not equivalent, which you can see by either (1) making `batch_size` differ from `input_dims[0]`, or (2) filling your arrays with non-constant values.

> why do I have to use `in_axes=(None, 0)` and not something like `in_axes=(0, )`?

If you set `in_axes=(0, )` for a function with two arguments, you get an error because the length of the `in_axes` tuple must match the number of arguments passed to the function. That said, it is possible to pass a scalar `in_axes=0` as a shorthand for `in_axes=(0, 0)`, but for your function this would lead to a shape error because the leading dimension of the arrays in `params` does not match the leading dimension of `input_vec`.